# Kubernetes: specify cluster context in apply command

Tags: kubernetes, config

I have multiple kubernetes clusters and want to ensure that when I `kubectl apply` a deployment, I'm targeting the correct cluster.

I have all my clusters configured in contexts in the root `/.kube/config` file but I don't want to rely on statefully switching my current context to the correct one before running each `apply` command.

i.e. This is not satisfactory

```
kubectl config use-context cluster-1-context
kubectl apply ./deploy-to-cluster-1.yml

kubectl config use-context cluster-2-context
kubectl apply ./deploy-to-cluster-2.yml
```

I read the docs on [config for multiple clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) and the only way I can find to do this is by copy/pasting the config for a particular cluster into a custom config file and specifying that with the `--kubeconfig` option on the `apply` command.

```
kubectl apply ./deploy-to-cluster-1.yml --kubeconfig ./config-cluster-1
kubectl apply ./deploy-to-cluster-2.yml --kubeconfig ./config-cluster-2
```

**This works**, but it seems really cumbersome.

For such a common requirement I'd expect there to just be a simple option on `apply`, or perhaps even a field in the deployment `yml`, that lets you specify (or restrict) the deployment to a particular context/cluster name, but I've read through a lot of the relevant documentation and can't find any such option.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There seems to be `--context=...` option.

```
kubectl options

The following options can be passed to any command:
...
      --context='': The name of the kubeconfig context to use
```

at least in version `v1.18.6`

Answer (score 9):

[`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) takes a `--context` option:

```sh
kubectl --context cluster-1-context apply -f ./deploy-to-cluster-1.yml
```

There's no way to specify or enforce this in resource YAML files; it's still possible to have accidents.

If you have multiple `.kube/config` files, you can also [set the `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable) to point at one of those.  This is understood by the standard Kubernetes SDKs, so almost all tools should support it.

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=./cluster-1-config.yml
kubectly apply -f ./deploy-to-cluster-1.yml
```

(Given the choice I would prefer this approach, because environment variables are shell-local but `kubectl config current-context` will affect all of my open terminal windows.  Standard tooling that configures the `.kube/config` file tends to default to the single shared global file, though, and teasing it apart can be a little tricky.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this?

You can use [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) tool to switch between contexts back and forth in a much easier way than kubectl.

```
USAGE:
  kubectx                   : list the contexts
  kubectx <NAME>            : switch to context <NAME>
  kubectx -                 : switch to the previous context
  kubectx -c, --current     : show the current context name
  kubectx <NEW_NAME>=<NAME> : rename context <NAME> to <NEW_NAME>
  kubectx <NEW_NAME>=.      : rename current-context to <NEW_NAME>
  kubectx -d <NAME>         : delete context <NAME> ('.' for current-context)
                              (this command won't delete the user/cluster entry
                              that is used by the context)
  kubectx -u, --unset       : unset the current context

$ kubectx minikube
Switched to context "minikube".

$ kubectx -
Switched to context "oregon".

$ kubectx -
Switched to context "minikube".

$ kubectx dublin=gke_ahmetb_europe-west1-b_dublin
Context "dublin" set.
Aliased "gke_ahmetb_europe-west1-b_dublin" as "dublin".
```

As it stands out today there is no way to specify context as part of deployment yaml. You can submit a feature request in kubernetes GitHub repo for this.

Comment: Thanks, good to know about `kubectx`, but the syntax of `kubectl config use-context` isn't the issue, it's the stateful nature of it. I need the context defined inline in the `apply` command - it needs to be atomic.